# Jest calling actual implementation instead of mock

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

So, I have the following class leveraging on mongo db client:

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongo'; //official mongo client
//... 
async retrieveDataFromMongo() {
     client = await connectToMongo();
     //use the client
}

export async function connectToMongo() : Promise<MongoClient> { //I had to export it to make test work...

    ...
    return MongoClient.connect('connstring'); //I need a mocked client, ofc
}
```

now, in my test function I'm doing the following:

```
import * as my_module from '../src/mymodule'; //this imports the previous
import {mock} from 'jest-mock-extended'; //lib I found to mock interfaces
const mockedMongoClient = mock<MongoClient>(); //creating  fake mongo client

describe('MyMongoTests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      jest.spyOn(my_module , 'connectToMongo').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockedMongoClient)); //this should return mine
  });

   it.only('test1', async() => {
      await my_module.retrieveDataFromMongo( ... //it ignores my spyOn!!!

   }
```

Answer (score -2):

The spec function seems alright but have you tried replacing `mockReturnValue` with `mockResolvedValue`?

Here's the updated spec:

```
import * as my_module from '../src/mymodule'; //this imports the previous
import {mock} from 'jest-mock-extended'; //lib I found to mock interfaces
const mockedMongoClient = mock<MongoClient>(); //creating  fake mongo client

describe('MyMongoTests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(my_module , 'connectToMongo').mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(mockedMongoClient)); 
  });
    
  it.only('test1', async() => {
    await my_module.retrieveDataFromMongo()
  }
```